# How do I add annotation to existing PDF

Tags: java, pdf, annotations

I own date for add annotation that title & contents & pageNo & coordinate value.I want add annotation to existing PDF using these data. 
I tryed to add annotation to existing PDF using pdfbox(Java). I could add annotation new page that was inserted into the last part of an existing page, But I cannot add annotation to existing pages because of cannot understand how to access existing pages and how to add annotation the page.

Below is my code. Pls resoleve it.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationTextMarkup;

public class Sample{
  private String forannot[][];
  Sample(String[][] forannot){
    this.forannot = forannot;
  }
  public void tryaddannot() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    PDFParser pps = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(Filepath);
    pps.parse();
    PDDocument docs = pps.getPDDocument();

    try{
      //insert new page
      PDPage pages = new PDPage();
      docs.addPage(pages);
      List<PDAnnotationTextMarkup> annotations = pages.getAnnotations();

      //generate instanse for annotation
      PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);

      //set the rectangle
      PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
      position.setLowerLeftX(170);
      position.setLowerLeftY(125);
      position.setUpperRightX(195);
      position.setUpperRightY(140);
      txtMark.setRectangle(position);

      //set the quadpoint
      float[] quads = new float[8];
      //x1,y1
      quads[0] = position.getLowerLeftX();
      quads[1] = position.getUpperRightY()-2;
      //x2,y2
      quads[2] = position.getUpperRightX();
      quads[3] = quads[1];
      //x3,y3
      quads[4] = quads[0];
      quads[5] = position.getLowerLeftY()-2;
      //x4,y4
      quads[6] = quads[2]; 
      quads[7] = quads[5]; 
      txtMark.setQuadPoints(quads);
      txtMark.setContents("Highlighted since it's important");
      annotations.add(txtMark); 
      docs.save(Filepath);
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      docs.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add annotation to existing an page, do this:

```
    PDPage page = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
    try
    {
        List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
```

Your code mostly works in 1.8, it's the annotation that is hard to see. Some code errors:

change

```
PDFParser pps = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(Filepath);
```

to

```
PDFParser pps = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(Filepath));
```

and change

```
  List<PDAnnotationTextMarkup> annotations = pages.getAnnotations();
```

to

```
  List<PDAnnotation> annotations = pages.getAnnotations();
```

Also, it is better to get your document like this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(...), null);
```

To see where your annotation is, either click in Adobe Reader on the last page on "Comments", "Comments list". To make the annotation more visible, add this:

```
        PDGamma colourBlue = new PDGamma();
        colourBlue.setB(1);
        txtMark.setColour(colourBlue);
```

Comment: @MGM Please have a look here für 2.0: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddAnnotations.java?view=markup  This example shows how to add annotations and set the color etc. If you have further trouble, please create a new question.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you!  :)  (Later I've managed to find it there.)